# TextFormField Inside TabBar missing when typing

Tags: flutter, tabbar, flutter-textformfield

Iam new in flutter and I want to create from inside TabBar with Expanded and SingleChildScrollView. But when I try to type the TextFormField, I can't see what i type.

this is my view before typing :
[image]

and this is my view when I typing :

[image]

and this is my code :

```
return BlocListener<RegisterBloc, RegisterState>(
  listener: (context, state) {
    if (state is RegisterFailure) {
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text('${state.error}'), backgroundColor: Colors.red));
    }
  },
  child: BlocBuilder<RegisterBloc, RegisterState>(
    builder: (context, state) {
      return MaterialApp(
        home: DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: Scaffold(
              body: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage("assets/images/bg_login.png"),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    )),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(height: 105),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  topLeft: Radius.circular(22),
                                  topRight: Radius.circular(22))),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 23,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "Daftar Akun Baru",
                                style: blackTextTitleThirtyTwo,
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                child: Container(
                                    padding:
                                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 47),
                                    child: Container(
                                      child: Scaffold(
                                        appBar: PreferredSize(
                                          preferredSize:
                                          Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
                                          child: SafeArea(
                                            child: Column(
                                              children: [
                                                TabBar(tabs: [
                                                  Text(
                                                    "1. Data Diri",
                                                    style:
                                                    newBlackPrimaySixTeen,
                                                  ),
                                                  Text(
                                                    "2. Perusahaan",
                                                    style:
                                                    newBlackPrimaySixTeen,
                                                  )
                                                ])
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        body: TabBarView(children: [
                                          Expanded(
                                              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                                child: Column(children: [
                                                  SingleChildScrollView(
                                                    child: Column(
                                                      children: [
                                                        Container(
                                                          color: whiteTextBox,
                                                          height: 48,
                                                          child: TextFormField(
                                                            controller: _usernameController,
                                                            maxLines: 1,
                                                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                                contentPadding:
                                                                EdgeInsets.only(
                                                                    top: 14.5,
                                                                    bottom:
                                                                    14.5,
                                                                    left: 10),
                                                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                                    borderRadius:
                                                                    BorderRadius
                                                                        .circular(
                                                                        5),
                                                                    borderSide:
                                                                    BorderSide(
                                                                        color:
                                                                        grayPrimaryTwo)),
                                                                hintText:
                                                                "Nama Pengguna",
                                                                hintStyle:
                                                                smallHintGray),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          height: 37,
                                                        ),
                                                        Container(
                                                          color: whiteTextBox,
                                                          height: 48,
                                                          child: TextFormField(
                                                            controller: _email,
                                                            maxLines: 1,
                                                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                                contentPadding:
                                                                EdgeInsets.only(
                                                                    top: 14.5,
                                                                    bottom:
                                                                    14.5,
                                                                    left: 10),
                                                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                                    borderRadius:
                                                                    BorderRadius
                                                                        .circular(
                                                                        5),
                                                                    borderSide:
                                                                    BorderSide(
                                                                        color:
                                                                        grayPrimaryTwo,
                                                                        width:
                                                                        5.0)),
                                                                hintText:
                                                                "Email Pengguna",
                                                                hintStyle:
                                                                smallHintGray),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          height: 37,
                                                        ),
                                                        Container(
                                                          color: whiteTextBox,
                                                          height: 48,
                                                          child: TextFormField(
                                                            maxLines: 1,
                                                            controller: _tenant_id,
                                                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                                contentPadding:
                                                                EdgeInsets.only(
                                                                    top: 14.5,
                                                                    bottom:
                                                                    14.5,
                                                                    left: 10),
                                                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                                    borderRadius:
                                                                    BorderRadius
                                                                        .circular(
                                                                        5),
                                                                    borderSide:
                                                                    BorderSide(
                                                                        color:
                                                                        grayPrimaryTwo)),
                                                                hintText:
                                                                "(+62) Nomor Telepon",
                                                                hintStyle:
                                                                smallHintGray),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          height: 37,
                                                        ),
                                                        Container(
                                                          color: whiteTextBox,
                                                          height: 48,
                                                          child: TextFormField(
                                                            validator: (value) {
                                                              if (value!
                                                                  .isNotEmpty) {
                                                                return 'Kata Sandi Tidak Boleh Kosong';
                                                              } else {
                                                                return null;
                                                              }
                                                            },
                                                            controller:
                                                            _passwordController,
                                                            obscureText:
                                                            obscureText,
                                                            maxLines: 1,
                                                            decoration:
                                                            InputDecoration(
                                                                suffixIcon:
                                                                GestureDetector(
                                                                  onTap: () {
                                                                    setState(
                                                                            () {
                                                                          obscureText =
                                                                          !obscureText;
                                                                        });
                                                                  },
                                                                  child:
                                                                  obscureText
                                                                      ? Icon(
                                                                    Icons.visibility_off,
                                                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                                                  )
                                                                      : Icon(
                                                                    Icons.visibility,
                                                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                                                  ),
                                                                ),
                                                                contentPadding:
                                                                EdgeInsets.only(
                                                                    top:
                                                                    14.5,
                                                                    bottom:
                                                                    14.5,
                                                                    left:
                                                                    10),
                                                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                                    borderRadius:
                                                                    BorderRadius
                                                                        .circular(
                                                                        5),
                                                                    borderSide:
                                                                    BorderSide(
                                                                        color:
                                                                        grayPrimaryTwo)),
                                                                hintText:
                                                                "Kata Sandi",
                                                                hintStyle:
                                                                smallHintGray),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          height: 37,
                                                        ),
                                                        Container(
                                                          color: whiteTextBox,
                                                          height: 48,
                                                          child: TextFormField(
                                                            validator: (value) {
                                                              if (value!
                                                                  .isNotEmpty) {
                                                                return 'Kata Sandi Tidak Boleh Kosong';
                                                              } else {
                                                                return null;
                                                              }
                                                            },
                                                            controller:
                                                            _reTypePasswordController,
                                                            obscureText:
                                                            obscureText,
                                                            maxLines: 1,
                                                            decoration:
                                                            InputDecoration(
                                                                suffixIcon:
                                                                GestureDetector(
                                                                  onTap: () {
                                                                    setState(
                                                                            () {
                                                                          obscureText =
                                                                          !obscureText;
                                                                        });
                                                                  },
                                                                  child:
                                                                  obscureText
                                                                      ? Icon(
                                                                    Icons.visibility_off,
                                                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                                                  )
                                                                      : Icon(
                                                                    Icons.visibility,
                                                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                                                  ),
                                                                ),
                                                                contentPadding:
                                                                EdgeInsets.only(
                                                                    top:
                                                                    14.5,
                                                                    bottom:
                                                                    14.5,
                                                                    left:
                                                                    10),
                                                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                                    borderRadius:
                                                                    BorderRadius
                                                                        .circular(
                                                                        5),
                                                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                                        color:
                                                                        grayPrimaryTwo,
                                                                        width:
                                                                        0.5)),
                                                                hintText:
                                                                "Input Ulang Kata Sandi",
                                                                hintStyle:
                                                                smallHintGray),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          height: 69,
                                                        ),
                                                        Padding(
                                                          padding: const EdgeInsets
                                                              .symmetric(
                                                              vertical: 0),
                                                          child: Container(
                                                            height: 52,
                                                            width: double.infinity,
                                                            child: RaisedButton(
                                                              onPressed: () {},
                                                              elevation: 5,
                                                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                                  borderRadius:
                                                                  BorderRadius
                                                                      .circular(
                                                                      15),
                                                                  side: BorderSide(
                                                                      color:
                                                                      grayPrimaryTwo)),
                                                              color: grayDarkTwo,
                                                              padding:
                                                              EdgeInsets.all(
                                                                  10),
                                                              child: Text(
                                                                "Selanjutnya",
                                                                style:
                                                                whitePrimaryTextStyle,
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          height: 37,
                                                        ),
                                                        Padding(
                                                          padding: const EdgeInsets
                                                              .symmetric(
                                                              vertical: 0),
                                                          child: Container(
                                                            height: 52,
                                                            width: double.infinity,
                                                            child: RaisedButton(
                                                              onPressed: () {},
                                                              elevation: 5,
                                                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                                  borderRadius:
                                                                  BorderRadius
                                                                      .circular(
                                                                      15),
                                                                  side: BorderSide(
                                                                      color:
                                                                      purplePrimary)),
                                                              color: Colors.white,
                                                              padding:
                                                              EdgeInsets.all(
                                                                  10),
                                                              child: Text(
                                                                "Batal",
                                                                style:
                                                                purplePrimaryTextStyle,
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          height: 24,
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  )
                                                ]),
                                              )),
                                        ]),
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                    )),
                              )
                            ],
                          )),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);

enter code here
```

Please help me solve this issue. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May try the code below, just replace the text style, background image, and "2. Perusahaan" tab bar view page to your needs and you are read to go.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Debugg5 extends StatefulWidget {
  Debugg5({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Debugg5State createState() => _Debugg5State();
}

class _Debugg5State extends State<Debugg5> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget body(){
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage(""), // your bg image
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            )),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 105),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(22),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(22))),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 23,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Daftar Akun Baru",
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                            padding:
                            EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 47),
                            child: Container(
                              child: Scaffold(
                                appBar: PreferredSize(
                                  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
                                  child: SafeArea(
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        TabBar(tabs: [
                                          Text(
                                            "1. Data Diri", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            "2. Perusahaan", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                          )
                                        ])
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                body: TabBarView(children: [
                                  SingleChildScrollView(
                                    child: Column(children: [
                                      SingleChildScrollView(
                                        child: Column(
                                          children: [
                                            Container(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              height: 48,
                                              child: TextFormField(
                                                maxLines: 1,
                                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                  contentPadding:
                                                  EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      top: 14.5,
                                                      bottom:
                                                      14.5,
                                                      left: 10),
                                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                      borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius
                                                          .circular(
                                                          5),
                                                      borderSide:
                                                      BorderSide(
                                                          color:
                                                          Colors.grey)),
                                                  hintText:
                                                  "Nama Pengguna",
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(
                                              height: 37,
                                            ),
                                            Container(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              height: 48,
                                              child: TextFormField(
                                                maxLines: 1,
                                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                  contentPadding:
                                                  EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      top: 14.5,
                                                      bottom:
                                                      14.5,
                                                      left: 10),
                                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                      borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius
                                                          .circular(
                                                          5),
                                                      borderSide:
                                                      BorderSide(
                                                          color:
                                                          Colors.white,
                                                          width:
                                                          5.0)),
                                                  hintText:
                                                  "Email Pengguna",),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(
                                              height: 37,
                                            ),
                                            Container(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              height: 48,
                                              child: TextFormField(
                                                maxLines: 1,
                                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                  contentPadding:
                                                  EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      top: 14.5,
                                                      bottom:
                                                      14.5,
                                                      left: 10),
                                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                      borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius
                                                          .circular(
                                                          5),
                                                      borderSide:
                                                      BorderSide(
                                                          color:
                                                          Colors.white)),
                                                  hintText:
                                                  "(+62) Nomor Telepon",
//                                                              hintStyle: Colors.white
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(
                                              height: 37,
                                            ),
                                            Container(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              height: 48,
                                              child: TextFormField(
                                                validator: (value) {
                                                  if (value
                                                      .isNotEmpty) {
                                                    return 'Kata Sandi Tidak Boleh Kosong';
                                                  } else {
                                                    return null;
                                                  }
                                                },
                                                obscureText:true,
                                                maxLines: 1,
                                                decoration:
                                                InputDecoration(
                                                  suffixIcon:
                                                  GestureDetector(
                                                    onTap: () {
                                                      setState(
                                                              () {
//                                                                        obscureText =
//                                                                        !obscureText;
                                                          });
                                                    },
                                                    child:
                                                    true
                                                        ? Icon(
                                                      Icons.visibility_off,
                                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                                    )
                                                        : Icon(
                                                      Icons.visibility,
                                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  contentPadding:
                                                  EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      top:
                                                      14.5,
                                                      bottom:
                                                      14.5,
                                                      left:
                                                      10),
                                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                      borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius
                                                          .circular(
                                                          5),
                                                      borderSide:
                                                      BorderSide(
                                                          color:
                                                          Colors.white)),
                                                  hintText:
                                                  "Kata Sandi",
//                                                              hintStyle: Colors.white
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(
                                              height: 37,
                                            ),
                                            Container(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              height: 48,
                                              child: TextFormField(
                                                validator: (value) {
                                                  if (value
                                                      .isNotEmpty) {
                                                    return 'Kata Sandi Tidak Boleh Kosong';
                                                  } else {
                                                    return null;
                                                  }
                                                },
                                                obscureText:
                                                true,
                                                maxLines: 1,
                                                decoration:
                                                InputDecoration(
                                                  suffixIcon:
                                                  GestureDetector(
                                                    onTap: () {
                                                      setState(
                                                              () {
//                                                                        obscureText =
//                                                                        !obscureText;
                                                          });
                                                    },
                                                    child:
                                                    true
                                                        ? Icon(
                                                      Icons.visibility_off,
                                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                                    )
                                                        : Icon(
                                                      Icons.visibility,
                                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  contentPadding:
                                                  EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      top:
                                                      14.5,
                                                      bottom:
                                                      14.5,
                                                      left:
                                                      10),
                                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                      borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius
                                                          .circular(
                                                          5),
                                                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                          color:
                                                          Colors.white,
                                                          width:
                                                          0.5)),
                                                  hintText:
                                                  "Input Ulang Kata Sandi",
//                                                              hintStyle: Colors.white
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(
                                              height: 69,
                                            ),
                                            Padding(
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets
                                                  .symmetric(
                                                  vertical: 0),
                                              child: Container(
                                                height: 52,
                                                width: double.infinity,
                                                child: RaisedButton(
                                                  onPressed: () {},
                                                  elevation: 5,
                                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                      borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius
                                                          .circular(
                                                          15),
                                                      side: BorderSide(
                                                          color:
                                                          Colors.white)),
//                                                            color: grayDarkTwo,
                                                  padding:
                                                  EdgeInsets.all(
                                                      10),
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    "Selanjutnya",
//                                                              style: whitePrimaryTextStyle,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(
                                              height: 37,
                                            ),
                                            Padding(
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets
                                                  .symmetric(
                                                  vertical: 0),
                                              child: Container(
                                                height: 52,
                                                width: double.infinity,
                                                child: RaisedButton(
                                                  onPressed: () {},
                                                  elevation: 5,
                                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                      borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius
                                                          .circular(
                                                          15),
                                                      side: BorderSide(
                                                        color: Colors.purple,
                                                      )),
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                  padding:
                                                  EdgeInsets.all(
                                                      10),
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    "Batal",
//                                                              style:
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(
                                              height: 24,
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    ]),
                                  ),
                                  SingleChildScrollView(
                                    child: Column(children: [
                                      SingleChildScrollView(
                                        child: Column(
                                          children: [
                                            Container(height: 100, color: Colors.blue,),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    ]),
                                  ),
                                ]),
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            )),
                      )
                    ],
                  )),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          width: size.width,
          height: size.height,
          child: body(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's work. Thanks!